# Не работает Python в IDE, но работает в cmd. Как решить?

Tags: python, windows

Начал работать с питоном. Почему не работают в IDE команды pip install и т. д.? В IDE работает только print и примитивные команды. А вот в cmd работает все.

Comment: вопрос должен быть развернутым. какое IDE? как вы в IDE запускаете pip install и т. д. Только постарайтесь обойтись БЕЗ скриншотов.

Comment: Подозреваю под IDE имеется в виду интерпретатор, запущенный в интерактивном режиме. Он работает только с синтаксисом самого питона и выполняет код. Pip это отдельная програмка для работы с зависимостями. В синтаксисе python нет команды pip.

Answer (score 0):

IDE - это интегрированная среда разработки. Если у вас IDE Python, то в данной среде вы вводите команды языка, не более того.
pip - это система управления пакетами. Да, она написана на языке Python, но это не команда языка, поэтому логично, что у вас она не работает в среде, а работает в командной строк. Именно так и задумано.
Если хотите изучить данный вопрос более подробно - погуглите.

Comment: Пожалуйста, [не посылайте в гугл](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3923/548252). Если вы не знаете ответ, просто не отвечайте на вопрос. Человек может погуглить по этой проблеме, которая  написана в вопросе. Представьте, человек зайдёт сюда, и что он увидит? Ему снова предложат пойти в гугл. И так до бесконечности.

Comment: Хорошо. Я вас услышал. На мой взгляд, ответ я сформировал. А вот если уж человек хочет почитать что-то по теме ещё больше, то гугл... но ваш комментарий я понял.